# Looking to share my experience in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I am working on my own fun project and I would like to share my thoughts, intentions and experiences on Stack Overflow. The parts of my project I'd like to post about focus on RabbitMQ, Websockets and the STOMP protocol.

I have found that there isn't very clear documentation around my specific use case so I'd like to share my experience to preserve for anyone looking to do something similar as well as gain feedback from others on how I approach things.

Stack Overflow seems to be a forum that centers on questions asked and answered so that information is there for others. I don't have any specific questions but would like to create documentation and possible discussion. Is Stack Overflow the right forum for that?

Comment: I'm surprised there's no blog.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites [are not discussion forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum), so discussion-based posts would not be appropriate for Stack Overflow, however you can certainly contribute documentation.

For specific topics, you can create a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Make sure what you post is actually an on-topic question however, self-answered questions must also be good questions.

There is also now [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) where you can document approved topics. The [RabbitMQ documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rabbitmq/topics) looks like it could use some love.

Comment: Glad I asked before proceeding. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: +1, we couldn't have explained better ourselves.

Comment: @Elsporko You may also consider writing a blog, especially if you are talking about integrating distinct technologies together as that sort of thing doesn't really have a place in specific documentation.

Comment: I am considering that but I started here for how far and wide this site reaches. The responses would be better and would produce a richer discussion for anyone looking for similar information in the future.

Comment: @Elsporko asking and answering your own question can be *very* dangerous for new users.  People are more likely to vote to close and downvote these questions/answers if they are not **perfect**.  I'd really suggest you search for other people who had issues you faced and add answers to their questions (as long as the questions aren't old or already answered!), as downvotes on new accounts can result in an automatic post ban.  It would be awful to get one just because you were trying to help others...